# Drupal - Grabbing and Looping NID of CCK Nodereference field

Tags: php, reference, drupal-6, cck

cant seem to work out how i grab multiple nids of a node reference field.

$node->field_name[0]['nid'] picks up the node id of the cck node reference field.

however when that cck node reference field has more than one value i get stuck!

my php is abit sketchy atm so working with arrays and loops is being quite difficult!

here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ((array)$node->field_industry as $item) { ?>
  <li><a href="../industry/company/<?php print --NODEID--?>"><?php print  $item['view'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

unless I am missing something, the following should work

```
<?php foreach ($node->field_industry as $item) { ?>
  <li><a href="../industry/company/<?php print $item['nid']?>"><?php print  $item['view'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can't add multiple references within one node reference field... however i would simply create my own textfield (field_multireferences) where i would type in my references: 12;43;65;21;...

now...

$myArray = explode(';', $node->field_multireferences[0]['view']);

foreach($myArray as....)
...

of course that wouldn't support auto completion etc.

Comment: I currently have a content type called industry and a content type called company. company holds a cck field called industry which is a Node reference type. the widget type is a select list in which you can select upto 6 values.

i currently have the company node printing out the relevant data. when it gets to industry it displays ALL values selected with a link to its original node. what i need is that specific NID to use it to link the industry text elsewhere.